# How can I change the return value of a function from within a sub-function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I am having trouble getting the following function to return true when the a holiday is detected.  The Alert fires correctly, but result always returns false.  I understand that this is a problem with variable scope, but am unsure how to *properly* fix it.

```
function isHoliday(date,currentProvince) {
  var calDate = new Date(date);
  var result = false;
  $.get(
    "@Url.Content("~/Holidays/HolidayList/?province=")"+currentProvince, 
    function(data) {
      for (h=0; h<data.length; h++) {
        holidayDate = new Date(
          parseInt(data[h].date.replace("\/Date\(","").replace("\)\/",""))
        );
        if (holidayDate.getTime() == calDate.getTime()) {
          alert("HOLIDAY");
          result = true;
        }
      }
    }
  );

  return result;
}
```

Am I able to somehow change the parameters of function(data) in the $.get statement to pass the variable in and out?  Or is there a beter way?

Comment: hey look another "ajax is asynchronous" question

Answer (score 2):

The function returns before the ajax call is completed; that is what the callback in the `$.get` is for, and why this is *asynchronous*.

if you want to get the result from this ajax call, then you need to wire up the rest of your logic to be the callback from this call, like so:

```
function isHoliday(date,currentProvince, callback) {

                var calDate = new Date(date);
                $.get("@Url.Content("~/Holidays/HolidayList/?province=")"+currentProvince, function(data) {
                    for (h=0; h<data.length; h++) {
                        holidayDate= new Date(parseInt(data[h].date.replace("\/Date\(","").replace("\)\/","")));
                        if (holidayDate.getTime() == calDate.getTime()) {
                            alert("HOLIDAY");
                            callback(true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            callback(false);
                        }
                    }
                 });
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

A normal function returns and exits the function.

On the contrary, when performing an asynchronous ajax request, it must wait arbitrarily as long as it needs to until the request is completed and sent back to you.

So, you cannot rely on a function return value when your function executes an ajax call.

a decent way to get around the problem is to write a callback into your function, like this:

```
function isHoliday(date,currentProvince, myCallback) {
    var calDate = new Date(date);
    var result = false;
    $.get("@Url.Content("~/Holidays/HolidayList/?province=")"+currentProvince, function(data) {

        myCallback();

    });
}

var callback = function() {
    for (h=0; h<data.length; h++) {
        holidayDate= new Date(parseInt(data[h].date.replace("\/Date\(","").replace("\)\/","")));
        if (holidayDate.getTime() == calDate.getTime()) {
            alert("HOLIDAY");
            result = true;
        }
    }
    //do whatever else you need to do after the ajax completes
};

isHoliday("12/01/19", "someProvince", callback);
```

Comment: Kristian is right. You'll need to return what's called a promise. Here's a [video tutorial](http://tutsplus.com/lesson/deferreds/) on how to use them (and deferreds) in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your get request is asynchronous but javascript continues to execute. Therefore, it reaches `return result` before the get request is handled